# Convert string to char 2d array

Tags: c++

I was wondering does anyone know how to convert a string into a 2d array? This was my attempt:

```
string w;
char s[9][9];
int p=0;
getline(cin, w);
while(p != w.size())
{
  for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
      s[k][j] = w[p];
      p++;
    }
  }
}
  cout << "nums are: " << endl;
  for(int k = 0; k < 9; k++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j <9; j++)
    {
      cout << s[k][j];
    }
  }
```

But the numbers don't print out correctly. I want s[k][j] to print out everything in w but it simply prints out gibberish. I also noticed if i do string[81] then I get a whole bunch of errors. Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: What output does it produce and what output do you expect? Please, be more specific.

Comment: Well I expected it to output everything from string w into the 2-D char array s. Could you help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Make sure your string `w` gets read successfully and contains enough elements (at least 81). In your output you probably want to insert a line break after printing 9 characters. ... and to answer the question from your last comment: yes, we could do your homework but that won't help you.

Comment: You should provide an example input and the output you would expect from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const int NUM_ROWS = 9;
const int NUM_COLS = 9;

string w;
char s[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];

getline(cin, w);

if (w.size() != (NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS))
{
    cerr << "Error! Size is " << w.size() << " rather than " << (NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS) << endl;
    exit(1);
}

for (int count = 0; count < w.size(); count++)
{
    if (!isdigit(w[count]) && w[count] != '.')
    {
        cerr << "The character at " << count << " is not a number!" << endl;
    }
}

for (int row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++)
    {
        s[row][col] = w[col + (row * NUM_COLS)];
    }
}

cout << "Nums are: " << endl;

for(int row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++)
    {
        cout << s[row][col] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Based on our chat, you might want this:

```
const int NUM_ROWS = 9;
const int NUM_COLS = 9;

string w;
char s[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];

while (!cin.eof())
{
    bool bad_input = false;

    getline(cin, w);

    if (w.size() != (NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS))
    {
        cerr << "Error! Size is " << w.size() << " rather than " << (NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS) << endl;
        continue;
    }

    for (int count = 0; count < w.size(); count++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(w[count]) && w[count] != '.')
        {
            cerr << "The character at " << count << " is not a number!" << endl;
            bad_input = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (bad_input)
        continue;

    for (int row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++)
        {
            s[row][col] = w[col + (row * NUM_COLS)];
        }
    }

    cout << "Nums are: " << endl;

    for(int row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++)
        {
            cout << s[row][col] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow thanks, no just a 2d char array is fine. I just have 1 question then--when I try to output it, the first character in the 2d array is deleted. Might you know why/the fix for this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. That's a strange problem to have. When you do: `cout << w << endl;` are all of the characters there?

Comment: You did the `cout` after the call to `getline`?

Comment: I called the cout at the end after i put the line where nums are:

Might it have to do the \0 in char arrays?

Comment: I'm a little confused. You don't need to worry about `\0` for `std::string`, which is the type of `w`. Also, you aren't printing out any character arrays. You are printing out each element (which is a `char`, not `char*`), so you don't need to worry about `\0` there either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18351/discussion-between-user1567909-and-geoff-montee)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't described what you're trying to do very well and you haven't described the problem you're encountering, so the following is just based on guesses.

So it looks what you're trying to do is take a string like:

> The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.

And put that into a 2D array like:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0 T h e   q u i c k
1   b r o w n   f o
2 x   j u m p e d  
3 o v e r   t h e  
4 l a z y   d o g s
5 . x x x x x x x x
6 x x x x x x x x x
7 x x x x x x x x x
8 x x x x x x x x x
```

One thing wrong with your code is that as you copy values from `w` into `s` you don't ensure that the index `p` is actually within the bounds. You seem to have attempted to deal with this in the line that says `while(p != w.size())`; but that's an outer loop that does not protect `p` from being incremented out of bounds and used in the inner loops. Instead you'd have to put something like `p++; if (p==w.size()) break;` inside the inner most loop where you increment `p`. Or better yet, you should iterate over the string instead of over the array. Something like the following pseudo-code would replace your entire `while(p){for(k){for(j){}}}` set of loops.:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<w.size(); ++i) {
    int k = compute target row from i
    int j = compute target column from i
    s[k][j] = w[i]
}
```

Also, here's some code to better visualize the array as you're debugging.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char s[9][9] = {"The","quick","brown","fox","jumped","over","the","lazy","dogs."};

    // your code to get input and copy it into the array goes here
    //
    // for(size_t i=0; i<w.size(); ++i) {
    //     int k = compute target row from i
    //     int j = compute target column from i
    //     s[k][j] = w[i]
    // }

    std::cout << "  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8\n";
    for (int i=0; i<9; ++i) {
        std::cout << i;
        for (int j=0; j<9; ++j)
            std::cout << ' ' << s[i][j];
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

If you run this program without any changes the output should look like this:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0 T h e      
1 q u i c k    
2 b r o w n    
3 f o x      
4 j u m p e d   
5 o v e r     
6 t h e      
7 l a z y     
8 d o g s .
```