# using getline to input into 2D array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, getline

for one of my assignments i have to cin a 2D array using getline. the maze design is made up on the spot.

```
16 10
################
#      #    #  #
# # #### ##   ##
# #      #######
# ###### #E    #
#S# #  # ### ### 
# # ## #     # #
# # ## ####### #
#              #
################
```

this is one of the sample inputs thats going to test our backtracking algorithm.

the 16 10 is the Column and Row of our maze.

i was wondering how i would go about to parse getline correctly so that my 2D array would fill using the maze given.

on a side note, i made a practice one where i dont have to cin and instead already have my array and i was wondering how i could tell it to start at the S.

sorry if theres a question on this but i didnt really see one where it was getlining into a 2D array in this format where you dont know your array size.

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992600/convert-string-to-char-2d-array ? Maybe you guys have the same homework.

Comment: I answered that question. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12992851/1732980 for direct link.

Comment: not the same but i believe this will work. its basically the same just i have to set my columns and rows. TY

Comment: I adapted it slightly for you. Check my new answer here.

Answer (score 1):

`getline` will only read one line at a time, so what you'll probably want to do is use a `for` loop to read each line in turn and store it as one row of your 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
size_t num_rows;
size_t num_cols;

cin >> num_rows >> num_cols;

char* maze = new char[num_rows * num_cols];

for (size_t row = 0; row < num_rows; row++)
{
     string line;

     getline(cin, line);

    if (line.size() != num_cols)
    {
        cerr << "Error! Size is " << line.size() << " rather than " << num_cols << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    for (size_t col = 0; col < num_cols; col++)
    {
        maze[(row * num_cols) + col] = line[col];
    }
}

cout << "Maze is: " << endl;

for(int row = 0; row < num_rows; row++)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < num_cols; col++)
    {
        cout << maze[(row * num_cols) + col];
    }

    cout << endl;
}

delete [] maze;
```

To figure out where start is:

```
size_t start_row, start_col;

for(int row = 0; row < num_rows; row++)
{
    bool found = false;

    for(int col = 0; col < num_cols; col++)
    {
        if (maze[(row * num_cols) + col] == 'S')
        {
            start_row = row;
            start_col = col;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

You can do similar things for the end point.

If you want to put the start point at a random empty spot, you can use `srand` and `rand`.

First, seed the pseudorandom number generator at the beginning of your program:

```
srand(time(0));
```

Then, determine a random start point:

```
size_t start_row, start_col;
bool found = false;

while (!found)
{
    start_row = rand() % num_rows;
    start_col = rand() % num_cols;

    if (isspace(maze[(start_row * num_cols) + start_col]))
    {
        maze[(start_row * num_cols) + start_col] = 'S';
        found = true;
    }
}
```

You can put the end spot in a random empty spot in a similar way.

People will sy that [`srand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/) and [`rand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/) aren't very good at generating random numbers. That is true, but it should be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: I don't use the delete do i? That's just for this example?

Comment: You use the `delete` when you are completely done with the array.

Comment: The `delete` operator does the opposite of the `new` operator. You need 1 `delete` for every `new`. But you don't call it until you are finished with the memory.

Comment: ive been working on it and have gotten it to work on a test maze where i know the starting point but im not sure how to make it so that it can find a random start point. any idea of how to iterate and make it stay at start?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "iterate, but stay at start". However, I added some code that should help you put the start in a random empty spot.