# problems converting character array to string array

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array, char

Hi i am quite new into programming and i need some small help on converting char array to string and i am not sure where has gone wrong. i need to get user input in %c and i input for the first input - aabcc and then clicks on enter
the second input - fsdff then enter again
3rd input - rewrr then enter again 
4th input - zzxcc and enter again the 
last input - asdfg.

But the outputs gives me array 1 = aabcc , 2nd array = fsdf (one of gone missing) 3rd array = f '\n' ... followed by 3rd 4th and 5th array displayed incorrectly. Thanks all in advanced.

```
int main()
{
   int i, j;
char ch[5][6];
char c[5][5];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    for (j = 0; j<5; j++)
        scanf("%c", &c[i][j]); // get user input

memcpy(ch[0], c[0], 5);
ch[0][5] = '\0';
memcpy(ch[1], c[1], 5);
ch[1][5] = '\0';
memcpy(ch[2], c[2], 5);
ch[2][5] = '\0';
memcpy(ch[3], c[3], 5);
ch[3][5] = '\0';
memcpy(ch[4], c[4], 5);
ch[4][5] = '\0';

printf("array 1 = %s, array 2 = %s , array 3 = %s , array 4 = %s , array 5 = %s ", ch[0], ch[1], ch[2], ch[3], ch[4]);
}
```

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992600/convert-string-to-char-2d-array

Comment: @user850307 your link for c++,but OP's requirement in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change below `scanf`

`scanf("%c", &c[i][j]);`

to

```
scanf(" %c", &c[i][j]);
       ^
       |
    space here
```

Reason behind it is, you are entering input as `aabcc<Enter>`, there are `6` characters in the input buffer. `scanf("%c")` reads the a, a, b, c and then c, interpreting them as the `aabcc`, but the newline character is still in the input buffer. Thats why you see newline as well when you try printing them.

Answer (score 1):

Your scanf buffer (c[][]) is too small to hold all the characters from a single entry.  As another writer pointed out, you have not added space for the '\n' character in your static allocation.

The size of your scanf character array (c[][]) should be = max no. of words x (max no. of chars in a word + 1)

The plus one is for the newline character.

```
#define MAXWORDSIZE 5
#define MAXWORDS 10

char c[MAXWORDS][MAXWORDSIZE + 1];      // Newline character
char ch[MAXWORDS][MAXWORDSIZE + 1 + 1]; // Newline and NUL character
```